# Matrix operations without loop MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix, xor

I have matrix `A(na*7)` and matrix `B(nb*7)`. (ex. `A(16*7)` and matrix `B(110*7)`)
A and B both have 1's and 0's as context.

I want to perform xor operation between each row of A and each row of B and count the number of 1's in the result and store it to another matrix C of size `na*nb`.

I know how to do so with for loops but I am wondering if there is any elegant way to do so without for loops in order to save speed.

**For example**

If size of `A` is `3*2` and size of `B` is `4*2`  i want to perform these operations:

```
sum(xor(A(1,:),B(1,:)))

sum(xor(A(2,:),B(1,:)))

sum(xor(A(3,:),B(1,:)))

l--------------l

sum(xor(A(1,:),B(2,:)))

sum(xor(A(2,:),B(2,:)))

sum(xor(A(3,:),B(2,:)))

l--------------l

sum(xor(A(1,:),B(3,:)))

sum(xor(A(2,:),B(3,:)))

sum(xor(A(3,:),B(3,:)))

l--------------l


sum(xor(A(1,:),B(4,:)))

sum(xor(A(2,:),B(4,:)))

sum(xor(A(3,:),B(4,:)))
```

Then I want each result to be stored in C. every set of 3 result is one row of C

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it with [bsxfun](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) and [permute](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/permute.html):

```
C = sum(bsxfun(@xor, permute(A, [1 3 2]), permute(B, [3 1 2])), 3)
```

Comment: can you write the command in such a way so it is parametrized please?

Comment: There is no need, the parameters are fixed. You don't have to change anything. Given two logical matrices (A and B), it will create a C matrix the way you specified in the question.

Comment: Yeap it seems it is working.. Thanks a lot.  can I ask what is the parameter [1 3 2] after A and [3 1 2 ] after B?

Comment: @DimitriC All numbers here refer to _dimensions_. That's why they don't depend on matrix sizes

Comment: Yeah. That's to permute the A matrix (which is MxNx1) to a Mx1xN matrix, and B (which is MxNx1) to a 1xMxN matrix, so bsxfun can operate properly (see bsxfun documentation for more details).

Comment: I have one last question. In terms of memory consumption which function is better to use? bsxfun or pdist??

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using [`pdist2`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/stats/pdist2.html) with the `'hamming'` option:

```
C = pdist2(A,B,'hamming')*size(A,2);
```